# Android: How to check if a pending Notification was delivered?

Tags: android

Is there a way for the sender of a `Notification` to know when that `Notification` is delivered to the receiver? i.e. Some method that can check if a the user has clicked on a given `Notification`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: Have my `Service` send a notification with a `PendingIntent` to start ActivityA. But if the user starts ActivityA without clicking on the Notification, I would like the service to cancel the `Notification` and send a direct Intent to ActivityA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow does not make a lot of sense to me. If the user opens ActivityA, why would you want to open another instance of ActivityA? I'm not sure what else "send a direct `Intent` to ActivityA" would mean. I would think a more conventional pattern would be for ActivityA to cancel the `Notification` in all cases, and ask the service for the latest data in all cases.

If that pattern is unsuitable for you, then have your `Notification` use a service `PendingIntent`. Have your service note that the user clicked on the `Notification`, then have the service start ActivityA. This gives the same effect for the user (tap on Notification, get ActivityA), but your service finds out about the tap.

Or, use an `Intent` in the activity `PendingIntent` that is distinct from the `Intent` that ActivityA normally starts with. Have ActivityA tell the service, "yo, I gots me an `Intent`, yo" in all cases. If the service raised a `Notification` and ActivityA indicates it started with the regular `Intent`, then tell ActivityA to do something. If the service raised a `Notification` and ActivityA indicates it started with the `Notification`'s `Intent`, do something else.

Comment: To clarify, if ActivityA is already opened, service will not open another instance of ActivityA (assuming it sets the correct flags for the StartActivity intent).

A "direct intent" means a sendBroadcast() to ActivityA when ActivityA is already active.

By service Service "noting" that the user clicked on a notification, do you mean set the PendingIntent to the Service itself?

Comment: " A "direct intent" means a sendBroadcast() to ActivityA when ActivityA is already active" Activities do not listen on broadcasts. An activity can dynamically register a BroadcastReceiver, though. "By service Service "noting" that the user clicked on a notification, do you mean set the PendingIntent to the Service itself?" I have no idea what this sentence means, sorry.